# mutable default package values in R

Tags: r, package, default-value

I am developing a package for R and I would like to set some package-wide defaults with the ability to modify them later. I know this sounds like global variables and thus evil, but I need this to  control profiling and debugging and to set the backend (the package can use a variety of external program to do its thing and I call them backends).

All these three settings should change at the same time for all the functions in a call stack. For example, if I call `mypackage::function1(profiling = T)` and `function1` calls `mypackage::function2` and `mypackage::function3` I would like profiling to be on for those too as far as that call is concerned. One solution could be to do
`mypackage::turn.on.profiling()` and have all the function refer to some package variable, but it requires trickery with locked environments and stuff like that.

Another could be dynamic scoping, simulated though the `sys.frame` family of functions (that is, once profiling is on, it's on for anything below that point on the stack). Don't tell me that profiling in R doesn't work like that because this is a different type of profiling, built on top of the existing one but different.

I have no doubt that I can hack it one way or another, but I was wondering if there is a canonical solution or at least some precedent in CRAN for something of this sort so that I won't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Why don't you just pass the argument on using the usual calling mechanisms? I think you're trying to be too complicated here.

Comment: Because you can build pretty complicated things with this package and I don't want to see function A passing the profiling option to function B then to function C etc. Plus I want to be able to profile programs built on this package where the profiling option is not made available or not correctly implemented. And the same is true for another option that I didn't mention here, the backend option, which allows you to compute things locally or on a cluster. So thanks for the call to simplicity, but no, the usual parameter passing mechanism seems inappropriate here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another simple way is to put the parameters in an environment object in your package and have your `turn.on.profiling`-like function modify it.

```
# Don't export this 
.profileOptions <- new.env(parent=emptyenv())
.profileOptions$enabled <- FALSE

# export this one
profilingEnabled <- function(flag = NA) {
    oldFlag <- .profileOptions$enabled
    if (!is.na(flag)) {
       .profileOptions$enabled = flag
    }
    oldFlag
}

# then use it
profilingEnabled() # returns TRUE or FALSE
profilingEnabled(TRUE) # enables profiling, returns previous state
```

Comment: I've just learned to use environments in more explicit ways and this solution didn't occur to me, but I was kind of searching around it. I think it is more modular than Joshua's. On the other hand, he seems to be using an official, blessed option mechanism whereas yours is your own (clever) idea. I like clever ideas but I like also to follow the law of the programming land. You both gave good ideas, thanks, I will mark one as correct eventually, but I would mark both if I could.

Comment: @piccolbo - I'd say that if you only have one simple parameter like this, the options way is better (at least easier!). If you have a bunch of parameters and want to ensure consistency between them, then this solution is better since the user can set options to whatever (invalid) values he wants, but here you control what gets set...

Answer (score 3):

You could set an option at the beginning of `function1` and unset it at the end or via `on.exit`.  Something like:

```
function1 <- function() {
  op <- options()       # current state of options
  on.exit(options(op))  # restore when function exits
  print(getOption("mypackage.profiling"))
  options(mypackage.profiling=TRUE)  # turn on profiling
  print(getOption("mypackage.profiling"))
}
options(mypackage.profiling=FALSE)
function1()
# [1] FALSE
# [1] TRUE
getOption("mypackage.profiling")
# [1] FALSE
```

You could also set options during package startup via `.onLoad`

Comment: This is a simple solution, I didn't know I could add my own options to  the general R mechanism. The only cons I see are: you are restoring all the options, not only the one changed, and this is more than is called for (some other function somewhere may be trying to effect a permanent option change). This is a simple fix of your solution. The other is that anyone can tamper with anything, I guess R is not that big on enforcing that kind of a boundary, but Tommy's solution below seem to have some more modularity to it.